# how to allow mixed content in safari version 16.3?

Tags: macos, safari

I have developed an application where i need to run a server locally.
The application needs to call the local server by using http(http request from https).
It works in chrome browser but whenever i want to run using safari browser it says "request cannot load due to access control check". I am using safari 16.3 version.
Is there any way to allow access to mixed content in safari browser version 16+?